# Appcelerator and JSON performance on Android

Tags: android, json, performance, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

This feels like something that may have been addressed already, but I could not find it, and so I thought I would ask.

I have this app that uses static dictionary data, which is being included with the app in the form of JSON files. Loading the needed JSON file on iOS works like a charm - iPhone 4s would read and parse any of those JSON files in under 4 seconds and it gets way better on later models.

Same code and same data compiled for Android would take 14 seconds to load on a Galaxy S6 and the delay comes from the call to JSON.parse().

Once data has been loaded in memory, making use of it is working fine on both iOS and Android.

This is all done using SDK 5.2.2.

Is there some way to speed up the JSON parsing process on Android? Or perhaps and alternative way for loading big chunks of data? (The data is basically a trie structure, which takes time to initialize and cannot be done on the fly. I use another app to initialize the trie structures and export them with JSON.stringify().)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It must be a huge file if it takes 4 seconds on an iPhone 4s. Some ideas to speed it up:

- Use an SQLite database.
- Split the file up in multiple parts.
- Prepend `module.exports =` to the file contents, rename it to `.js` and `require()` it as a CommonJS module.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the problem is not the iPhone 4s timing but the Android timing. I cannot use SQLite database for this - way too slow to search for partial matches in real time. ... The size of my JSON files is between 10 and 18 MB, which I realize is a lot but they contain pre-compiled dictionary models, which work perfectly once loaded in memory. ... The problem is that loading them on Android is slow. In fact both JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() are rather slow on Android.

Comment: So is turning them into CommonJS modules an option?